# Curl on windows + wamp for command line

Tags: curl

I am kinda to new this curl business, I have WAMP and curl has been commented out on the php.ini so its working, however i thought that i could run from the command line something like

curl www.google.com or curl -o example.html www.example.com

to see the results in the command line, however it doesnt seem to be working, which command line are they refering to? i am trying to do it on the windows command line or can it only be done on linux

```
'curl' is not recognized as an i
operable program or batch file.
```

sorry for my noobiness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP ships with the DLL component only. You need to install the curl command line utility from [cURL website](http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: Ah, i see i will download it straight await

Answer (score 1):

curl isn't included with Windows.  You'll need to download a Windows binary and put it somewhere in your PATH.